# Is it possible to update the class for a record in OrientDB after creating the record?

Tags: orientdb

I am creating Schema under **Graph Database** in **OrientDB**. I am creating a **class Entity** with few fields. Entity can be changed in the functional life cycle to StageOneEntity. So I created one more **class StageOneEntity** which extends Entity class.

If I create a record using **class Entity**, can I change the class to **StageOneEntity** afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the class is assigned on creation and never can be changed, unless you copy the object but it would have a different RID.

Answer (score 1):

YES, it is possible:

```
MOVE VERTEX #34:232 TO CLASS:StageOneEntity
```

or

```
MOVE VERTEX (SELECT FROM `Entity`) TO CLASS:StageOneEntity
```

to change class of all `Entity` records

https://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Move-Vertex.html

It is possible only for vertices (not edges) according to documentation. I had found no notes about `MOVE EDGE` command.

Comment: Note that this does not change the class of the vertices but copies them to another class.